# Translation / information about from some scrolls

Tags: translation

We have had in our family for some time a group of 4 scrolls with some Chinese text on them.  We would really appreciate a translation / some information about them?[image]

Answer (score 2):

the text is (i added the chopping):

霧歛雲收・曙色漸明・隱隱約約遠山青・見人家半啟扃・只聽得馬蹄兒・趷的趷蹬穿荒徑・睡犬早醒・白蘋岸・紅蓼汀・暗想眠鷗宿鷺驚

戊戌冬ｘ趙大年ｘ兹超作

ｘ are unrecognised characters

the first x, most likely means “imitate”, cause “趙大年” is a famous painter in 宋 dynasty

“兹超” is the art name of the author (陳達). so, “戊戌冬” would be the winter of the year 1958

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

> 戊戌冬ｘ趙大年ｘ兹超作
>
> ｘ are unrecognised characters

擬 is the act of imitate
The second X is the handwriting style of 本

so the last col reads 戊戌冬 擬趙大年本兹超作